# Unlock contract deploy address in Truffle testing using TestRPC?

Tags: solidity, truffle, testrpc

I'm trying to test a function in a contract that sends ether from itself to another contract address. However in my Truffle tests I keep getting `Uncaught Error: Error: could not unlock signer account`.  I have tried `web3.personal.unlockAccount`, however that doesn't appear to be supported in TestRPC?

Running TestRPC with `-u` flags doesn't help either because the contract address isn't in the list of accounts.

I thought it might be possible by using `--fork` but since Truffle does a fresh deploy on every test I can't get the deploy address to run `-u <address>` with `--fork` :(.

How can I either unlock this account so that I can test the functionality with Truffle, or workaround this to test that function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*I might be mistaken*, but it sounds like a little confusion in the way you're setting up the test.

You can't use truffle to make the deployed contract do anything *directly*. In fact, in ethereum, everything starts when someone signs a transaction and sends it. So, you can only send a transaction to the contract you want to test. To do *that*, one of the accounts testrpc gives you will have to sign the transaction.

So, your contract at 0x123 might look something like:

```
contract TestSend {

  function sendToOther(address receiver) payable returns(bool success) {
    if(!receiver.send(msg.value) throw; // send whatever was received

...
```

Maybe truffle gives you:

```
0x456
0x789
...
```

You could tell truffle to send from a sender to a receiver (first argument) and you would send that transaction to `0x123` which would be `TestSend.deployed()`:

```
testSend.sendToOther("0x789", {from: 0x456, value: 1})
```

where testSend is `TestSend.deployed()`.

In the example, the signer would be 0x456. The point being that it *is* one the accounts testrpc gives you. It has to be. There is no other way.

In case it helps ... It's a matter of style, but I like to start my tests by declaring all the players. Something like below gets things off to a good start so you can say things like `testSend.sendToOther(catcher,{from: sender, value: sendAmt});`

---

```
var Contract = artifacts.require("./Contract.sol");

contract('Contract', function(accounts) {

  var contract;
  var sendAmt = 10;
  var owner   = accounts[0];
  var sender  = accounts[1];
  var catcher = accounts[2];

  beforeEach(function() {
    return Contract.new({from: owner})
    .then(function(instance) {
       contract = instance;
    });
  });

  it("should ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Rob, this was great. I definitely had a misunderstanding of how I was writing the tests.  It's all working now :). Thanks a lot